# Matching number with regex

Tags: regex, validation, numbers

Need a single combined regex to match the following logic:
The number should be 8 digits long, the 8th digit should be the remainder of (the first 7 digits / 7).

for example: 8600878***6***

remainder = (the first 7 digit)/ 7 = 8600878 / 7 = 6

so the 8 digit 86008786 is valid number.

is it doable with regex?

Comment: You can get the number to be 8 digit long, but the math should be done by code in the language you're working

Answer (score -2):

It is not doable with regex. You cannot do math operations. It might be possible with a unary number, but would require a conversion and would be inefficient.